# Getting source of image stored in block by using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-cycle

I'm making a slider for my webpage and I'm using jquery's plugin called "Cycle". I have faced a problem with accessing source of images used in slider. It's quite hard to explain so here is my code from 'head' part:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#slider').before('<ul id="pager">').cycle({ 
        fx: 'scrollHorz',
        speed: 900,
        timeout: 5500,
        pause: 1,
        pager: '#pager',

        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
        return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + slide.src + '" width="120" height="65" /></a></li>'; 
        } 
    });
</script>
```

Here is the html part:

```
<div id="slider_container">
    <div id="slider">
        <div class="items">
            <img src="1.jpg"/>
            <div class="info">
                <h2>Tile Nr. 1</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="items">                         
            <img src="2.jpg"/>
            <div class="info">
                <h2>Tilte Nr. 2</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="pager">

    </div>
</div>
```

In my `slider` div I want to display blocks, each of them containing image and some title but in `pager` div I want to display only the images from those blocks used in `slider`. I'm sure that the problem is in `slide.src` expression in the third javascript. How should I change that expression to get the source of an image stored in appropriate `items` block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you set up a jsFiddle that sources the jquery files you need here?

My guess is that `slide.src` isn't what you want.  If `slide` is a reference to an element in the DOM, then you access its 'source' attribute like this: `$(slide).attr('src')`

Updated:

Turns out 'slide' is the containing div so we need this instead:

`$(slide).find('img').attr('src')`

Comment: Tried your suggestion but it didn't work..In my case slides are divs, classified by "items". I want to access the source of images that is stored in those divs

Comment: I'm sorry, what did you mean with 'Setting up jsFiddle'?

Comment: Yeah, then this code should work.  Let me know if it doesn't though.  jsfiddle.net is a popular way of sharing web code.  You can quickly show people what the problem is, and they can make quick changes and show you that they work.  Like this one I made from your code (although it can't find the jquery cycle file or the image files obviously): http://jsfiddle.net/n16k6cab/

Comment: I tried your code, but it still seems to not working. Here is my jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/n16k6cab/19/.

Comment: Ah ok.  So the 'slide' that is passed to the function is the 'div' that contains the 'img' element.  So to access the 'img' src, we do this instead: `$(slide).find('img').attr('src')`  Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n16k6cab/59/

Answer (score 0):

When you inspect the argument `slide` inside `pagerAnchorBuilder`-function you find slide being a div-element with class `items` and containing the img-element as first child-element. So you can access the img and it's src-attribute like so:

```
pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
    var source = $('img', slide).attr('src');
    return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + source + '" width="120" height="65" /></a></li>'; 
}
```

There are also some other ways of writing it, all with same result:

```
var source = $(slide).find('img').attr('src');
// or in native js
var source = slide.querySelector('img').getAttribute('src');
var source = slide.querySelector('img').src;
var source = slide.firstElementChild.src
```